# SSRS percentage of a total

Tags: reporting-services, percentage

I would like to be able to get the percentage of each row with relation of the whole total. Here is my formula:

```
=COUNTDISTINCT(Fields!ID.Value, "NameOfRowGrouping") / COUNTDISTINCT(Fields!ID.Value, "TopLevelGroupName")
```

The percentage it comes out is the percentage between row total and total of each group:

```
Group       Qty     %
---------------------
Group 1
MemberA       3   40%
MemberB       4   60%

Total         7

Group 2 
MemberC       2   50%
MemberD       2   50%

Total         4

Grand Total  11
```

I need to know the percentage with relation of the total for all groupings, like so:

```
Group       Qty     %
---------------------
Group 1
MemberA       3   30%
MemberB       4   40%

Total         7

Group 2 
MemberC       2   15%
MemberD       2   15%

Total         4

Grand Total  11  100%
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is calculate based on the dataset, not the table grouping:

```
=CountDistinct(Fields!ID.Value)/CountDistinct(Fields!ID.Value, "MyDatasetName")
```