# SSRS - Working out percentages

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

I need to work out the percentage in SSRS for the below data - sum the "Qty" of products where the Status = "Live" and then divide the it by the total "Qty" for all products:

Is it possible to this in SSRS expression or do I need to this in the sql query?

**Weeknum___Status_____Qty**

34__________Toxic______ 99

34__________    EOL______   1819

34__________Live_______3440

34__________BER_______361

34__________Live______1

34__________Live______386

34__________BER_______39

34__________EOL______498

Comment: Would [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308203/ssrs-percentage-of-a-total) help you find an answer?

Comment: It is possible to do this in an expression.

Answer (score 0):

Fisrt you will have to create a metrix that filter the status maybe like this

```
=Fields!Status.Value
```

Then in another colum you will have to put this

```
=FormatPercent(sum(Fields!Qty.Value)/(Sum(Fields!Qty.Value, "YOUR DATASET"),1)
```

And you will get the percentages over the total of the Qty