# Calculating percentage of total in SRSS

Tags: reporting-services

I just started working in SRSS and needed to some with calculating percentage of total in my table. In my stored procedure, my customers are in varchar format.

This is basically my table for now:

```
Some fees| Customers paying | % of total
Startfees| Count(Customers)(1)|  
**Total** COUNT(Customers)(2) | 3000
```

How can I calculate the percentage of COUNT of customers(1) by COUNT of customers of(2) which is the total? My Customers are in varchar format.

I kept my customers in the stored procedure in varchar to use the isnull function to keep the data report clear of nulls and such.

Comment: Anyone? Is there a way of doing in SSRS COUNT(Customers)/ total customers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSRS percentage of a total](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308203/ssrs-percentage-of-a-total)