# SSRS total percentage either less or greater than 100%

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I needed help with solving a problem. I found the expression code that solved the first part of my problem in this thread: [SSRS Percentage of a total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308203/ssrs-percentage-of-a-total/29070461?noredirect=1#comment46377085_29070461)

Now the second problem I discovered after implementing that same expression code that was voted in the above link , is that when I manually sum the percentages up, the the percentage is either less than 100% or more than 100 %. Not always 100%.

I have clicked in the expression formula box, and chosen the number format in properties to "P0", which basically is meant to only return percentages without any decimals.

If I try P1 or P2, the final total percentage still is greater than 100%.

What are some possible solutions so that the final total percentage is always 100% with P0?

Comment: Anyone who has any suggestion?

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out.  I would need to see more information, but there's an error with your initial calculations.  You could just set a conditional on your total box, like `IIF([sum of boxes] > 1, 1, [sum of boxes])`

Comment: I cannot use sum here as I am counting customer numbers and then dividing that result with reference to my dataset name.So it is like COUNTDISTINCT(field.xx.value)/COUNTDISTINCT(Field.xx.value,"My datasetname"). it returns the percentage, however the sum does not add up to 100%. It is either less or more than 100%. How can I fix this so the sum is always 100%?

Comment: If you add your parts of a whole, and it's not 1 whole, then your percentage calculation doesn't work.  When you say not 100%, is it off by just a few points?  This would be a rounding error.  Make sure you're casting your numbers to decimals, as integers will round off.

Comment: Any example how do that in SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

If you are dividing by integers, you'll have rounding issues.  Try casting them to decimals.  Taken from your other question:

Change this:

```
=CountDistinct(Fields!ID.Value)/CountDistinct(Fields!ID.Value, "MyDatasetName")
```

To this:

```
=CDec(CountDistinct(Fields!ID.Value)) / CDec(CountDistinct(Fields!ID.Value, "MyDatasetName"))
```

Then, when you display the information, make sure you set the text box properties to show proper percentage numbers(check the 'Numbers' tab in the Text Box Properties).

Also, if your calculations are fine and this is just a rounding issue, you could just hardcode your total textbox to 100%, if it is supposed to be exactly that every single time.