# SSRS percentage of a total with column groups

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I apologize in advance if this is not enough info or if it is confusing (This is my first post to the forum and it's a little hard to explain what i'm trying to do).  I have been researching this for a couple days now.  This article comes really close to what I need, but this person did not have column groups, just a a single column with an output: [SSRS percentage of a total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308203/ssrs-percentage-of-a-total).

Consider this layout and groups:

[image: Percent of Total Matrix and Groups]

The idea is to provide the percentage of the total records per PrimaryPayor per Company and then break it out by Year-Month.

This expression:

```
=CountDistinct(Fields!ID.Value, "Primary_Payor") / CountDistinct(Fields!ID.Value, "Company")
```

Results in this output (The first image is my output, the second is the desired output):

[image: Results (Updated)]

As you can see, the percentages do NOT group by Year-Month, instead just provides the total percentage of IDs per Payor per Company and repeats it for every Year-Month column.  How can I get the percent of Total IDs per payor, company, and month as it shows in the second result image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After editing my question, I thought of something I hadn't tried.

If I just use =CountDistinct(Fields!ID.Value), this gives the total count for each payor, company, month, plus, I added a Total row.

Then, if I reference those textbox values (instead of trying to calculate the percentage on the fly) divided by the total row, I get my results.  I just had to add a column inside of the column group. I should then be able to just Hide my "total" column and display only the percentages.

=ReportItems!Textbox50.Value / ReportItems!Textbox35.Value

Here is the output (with the total counts and then after hiding the "count" column):

[Final Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKVwB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=CountDistinct(Fields!ID.Value) / CountDistinct(Fields!ID.Value, "Company")
```

I removed the `Primary_Payor` scope leaving the function calculate the count in the cell scope `Primary_Payor` and `DOS_YrMo`.

**UPDATE:**

```
=CountDistinct(Fields!ID.Value) / CountDistinct(Fields!ID.Value, "DOS_YrMo")
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: This gives me the percent of the total count for the company by each month.  So, instead of each month column adding to 100%, each month adds to 10%, for example.  I need to get the percentage of each month's total count per company.  I'm wondering if what I'm wanting is even possible at this point.

Comment: @JBirrer, Is the expression cell in the `Primary_Payor` group scope?

Comment: I added an answer.  Hopefully this wasn't a waste of time for you.  Appreciate the help.  The solution you provided above is close (tried it a half dozen times hoping for a different result lol, but it does not separate the results by company, so I would end up with a 100% total after adding up all companies.