# SSRS Finding Percentage of Group vs Total

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, grouping, percentage

I created a table in visual studio showing case numbers listed per judge (grouped by judge) and now I need to create a summary table of that data.  I have the total case count per judge but I need to determine the percentage of cases that each judge has.  I found this article:

[SSRS percentage of a total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308203/ssrs-percentage-of-a-total)

but the answer discusses grouping by dataset, whereas I am working with row groups within the report and I haven't been able to find anything that speaks to that.

I tried just replacing the dataset name with the group names for each:

```
=sum(countdistinct(Fields!case_num.Value),"judge_group")/  
     sum(countdistinct(Fields!case_num.Value), "case_num")
```

also tried:

```
=sum(countdistinct(Fields!case_num.Value,"judge_group"))/
    sum(countdistinct(Fields!case_num.Value, "case_num"))
```

I also tried using just one group, the overall group "case_num" and I received an error message that my scope param is not valid for an aggregate function.

Comment: In the article you pointed to, replace the dataset name with the group name (judge) in the expression, where appropriate. That is really all there is to it.

Comment: @R.Richards Thank you, I put my response as an add on to my question since it was getting too long.

Comment: Can you show a sample of your dataset report design please.

Comment: I assume that you are showing these values as group totals. If so can you not do the calc by taking the textbox value instead of the dataset value?